# Additional Metadata on Celery 'FAILURE'

Tags: python, celery

Is it possible to send additional metadata with a Celery 'FAILURE' state?

Currently I'm only finding it possible to send exception data and nothing else. Ideally I'd like to send with it an array of extra information that can be picked up by my frontend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, after digging deeper into this, I found a way to achieve this:

There are a couple of tricks involved:

1. set the task state via `update_state`
2. make sure that the `meta` argument complies with what Celery expects for the `FAILURE` state
3. instruct Celery to remove the message from the queue but disable Celery's internal task state recording via `Ignore()`

For example:

```
from celery import states
from celery.exceptions import Ignore

@app.task(bind=True)
def task(self):
    try:
        raise ValueError('Some error')
    except Exception as ex:
        self.update_state(
            state=states.FAILURE,
            meta={
                'exc_type': type(ex).__name__,
                'exc_message': traceback.format_exc().split('\n')
                'custom': '...'
            })
        raise Ignore()
```

When retrieving the `AsyncResult`, the additional custom data is available via the `task.backend.get()` call:

```
task = tasks.task.s().delay()
meta = task.backend.get(task.backend.get_key_for_task(task.id))
json.loads(meta.decode('utf8'))['result']['custom']
```

If you are interested in some more background info on this, I've written a blog post about it: https://www.distributedpython.com/2018/09/28/celery-task-states - thanks for the inspiration ;-)

Comment: Thanks, it looks like I was close with a solution I was working on although I couldn't figure out a reliable way to get the custom data from the backend. I ended up with a solution that utilised on_failure to set a completely custom failure state.

Comment: Extremely informative post, thanks for linking!

Comment: hey, I tried your way but the tasks are stuck on `STARTED` state, do you have any idea why it is so?

Comment: are these tasks that are stuck in the STARTED state being picked up by your worker at all?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. However, you can access the task's traceback property to get the stacktrace, does that help?

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I'm looking to send extra information that isn't related to the exception.